# Unable to call Patch method of Web API in ASP.NET Core

Tags: http, asp.net-core, asp.net-core-webapi, http-patch

My API has a method of type Patch that I need to call from the client. This method is:

```
[HttpPatch("{id}")]
public StatusCodeResult Patch(int id, [FromBody]JsonPatchDocument<Reservation> patch)
{
    Reservation res = Get(id);
    if (res != null)
    {
        patch.ApplyTo(res);
        return Ok();
    }
    return NotFound();
}
```

I am trying to call it from my client whose code is:

```
[HttpPost]
public async Task<IActionResult> UpdateReservationPatch(int id, Reservation reservation)
 {
     using (var httpClient = new HttpClient())
     {
         var request = new HttpRequestMessage
         {
             RequestUri = new Uri("http://localhost:8888/api/Reservation/" + id),
             Method = new HttpMethod("Patch"),
             Content = new StringContent("[{ \"op\":\"replace\", \"path\":\"Name\", \"value\":\"" + reservation.Name + "\"},{ \"op\":\"replace\", \"path\":\"StartLocation\", \"value\":\"" + reservation.StartLocation + "\"}]", Encoding.UTF8, "application/json")
         };

         var response = await httpClient.SendAsync(request);
     }
     return RedirectToAction("Index");
 }
```

I am failing to do so and getting error.

> StatusCode: 400, ReasonPhrase: 'Bad Request', Version: 1.1, Content: System.Net.Http.HttpConnectionResponseContent, Headers:
> {
> Server: Microsoft-IIS/10.0
> X-Powered-By: ASP.NET
> Date: Tue, 28 Jul 2020 12:25:24 GMT
> Content-Type: application/problem+json; charset=utf-8
> Content-Length: 370
> }}

What can be the problem?

Comment: Do you receive any response body? Sometimes it can tell you what the error is.

Comment: Yes i received 400 error and the description is listed in the question itself.

Comment: Are you using the code from [here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/web-api/jsonpatch?view=aspnetcore-3.1#json-patch-addnewtonsoftjson-and-systemtextjson) to register the JSON Patch support?

Comment: @KirkLarkin no, is it necessary? Because when I made the exact same code in asp.net core 2.0 then it worked right away. It is in asp.net 3.1 that it is not working.

Comment: 3.0+ uses System.Text.Json (by default), which doesn't support JSON Patch. You can either switch entirely to Json.NET, or use that code to add Json.NET _only_ for the JSON Patch support.

Comment: @KirkLarkin great. Your link solved my problem.